# Adding quotation mark in array values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings in object form received from file, only I need to add quotation mark around parameter names of objects which are strings inside an array and around their values between square brackets to convert those strings to proper objects.

```
["{Durdham Hall Electric: [e4.kwh]}", "{University Hall Substation: [e1.kwh]}", 
"{University Hall Substation: [e2.kwh]}"]
```

I have no idea how to loop through values and to add required symbol in required part.

Comment: is this coming from a json file?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to supply yourself with proper JSON (ie JSON where the objects aren't quoted, but the keys/values are)?

Comment: Consider fixing the _source_ / _how you get the data_. You can't even eval those strings.

Comment: Data coming from one javascript file to another javascript file in array form. Those values are obtained from option element value, so there is no way of sending them in other form

Comment: I bet you there is. What code are you using to get the option element values into the array?

Comment: Well in this form    -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                           
                var options = [];
options.push('<option value="' + '{' + data[devices][1]+': ' + '['+ 'e' + i + '.kwh' +']' + '}' + '" >'
                          + meterName + '</option>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change

```
options.push('<option value="' + '{' + data[devices][1] + ': ' + '[' + 'e' + i + '.kwh' + ']' + '}' + '" >' + meterName + '</option>')
```

to something like this, then you get a little nice parsable JSON

```js
var data = [[0, 'Durdham Hall Electric:']],
    devices = 0,
    meterName = 'meterName',
    i = 3,
    options = [];

options.push('<option value="' + '{ \\"device\\": \\"' + data[devices][1] + '\\", \\"kwh\\": \\"' + 'e' + i + '\\"}' + '">' + meterName + '</option>');

alert(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex and `forEach` to do this:

```js
var data = ["{Durdham Hall Electric: [e4.kwh]}", "{University Hall Substation: [e1.kwh]}", 
"{University Hall Substation: [e2.kwh]}"];

data.forEach(function(v,i){
  data[i] = JSON.parse( v.replace(/{(.+):\s\[(.*)\]}/g, '{"$1":["$2"]}') );
});

console.log(data); // Open your console to see the results
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are always starting with a { you can use substring and then combine the string back together.

```
String part1;
String part2;
String result;

String str = "{Durdham Hall Electric: [e4.kwh]}"
```

Then use index of to find the :

```
part1 = str.subString(1, str.indexOf(":"));
part2 = str.subString(str.indexOf(":"), str.length());
result = "{\"" + part1 + "\"" + part2;
```

Believe something like this could work however you do have to make some assumptions. This is only for a single element so you would have a loop for each item in your string array.